# Django and Ajax issue with validate data

Tags: python, ajax, django

My forms at Django project send with POST method( using AJAX) some data like name

At my views.py I try validate it to store at my DB.

views.py

```
def create(request):

    name = request.POST['name']


    if len(name) == 1 and len(surname) == 1 and len(message) == 1:
        Create.objects.create(
            name=name,
        )

        return redirect('post:table')

    else:
        return redirect('index:index')
else:
    return redirect('index:index')
```

Issue: 
**redirect not working. Why?**

1# Example input: 
name = a =
Output:
All right -> stored at DB

2# Example input:
name = aaa

Output:
Wrong data and dont stored at DB -> but return redirect not working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using an Ajax request. That means you're *explicitly* telling the browser to request information without changing the page. You need to manage the redirect in your Ajax success method.

In any case, you shouldn't redirect on validation failure, you should stay on the same page and allow the user to correct the data and resubmit.

Comment: So... Maybe can I use HttpResponce method in Django, and at Ajax script callback function? 
Successfunction in my case don't working.